# How to copy the latest folder from my aws ec2 instance to my local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

How do I copy the latest subdirectory from my aws ec2 instance to my local machine?

I have a directory dumps in my aws ec2 instance.
The path of my directory is /home/ubuntu/dumps

My dumps directory has subdirectories on the basis of timestamp..for eg-20160613120500, 20160613170545 and so on. How do I copy the latest subdirectory from my dumps folder to my local machine??

The command I have used is -

```
   scp -r -i amanaws.pem ubuntu@ec2-instance:~/dumps $local_target_directory
```

How do i modify it?

Comment: how frequently do you want to run this command or you copy the directory that was created yesterday?

Comment: Its like i create 4-5 database dumps in my dumps directory in the local machine every day. So, each time i run the scp command from my local machine I want to copy the latest dump in the dumps folder.

Comment: I am not sure..I may run it frequently or maybe once every day. Does the time I run matter?

Comment: there is a way you can copy the directories which were created yesterday

Comment: You can create a script like this "for i in `f/home/ubuntu/dumps f -ctime -1`
do
scp -r -i amanaws.pem ubuntu@ec2-instance:~/dumps $local_target_directory
done"

Comment: @error2007s Hey, its still copying all the files from the dumps directory from the terminal to the folder on my local machine.
Btw, you got my question, right?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to transfer data like this is `rsync`.  You can point it at the folder where you store your dumps, and it will copy over the new files or those that have changed, skipping over the files that already exist on both machines.

Rsync can run over ssh, so you can do something like this:

```
rsync -a --progress -e "ssh -i amanaws.pem" ubuntu@ec2-instance:~/dumps $local_target_directory
```

To copy just the newest file, try something like this:

```
scp -i amanaws.pem ubuntu@ec2-instance:~/dumps/$(ssh -i amanaws.pem ubuntu@ec2-instance 'ls -t dumps | head -1') .
```

This combines scp with the results of running a short script `ls -t dumps | head -1` remotely.

Comment: Thank you, sir! But, that's not what I exactly want to do. Let' say there are 5 dumps per day, after every 2-3 days so I just want to copy the latest dump from my remote ec2 instance to my local mahince.

Comment: Ok, updated with an alternative to copy just the one most recent file.